# ArcPy SearchCursor row format

Tags: arcpy, cursor, format

I set up a script to print some statistics about line segments. The "logfile" is basically the same as "print", but to a textfile instead of on screen only.

> LogFile("Feature {0} has a length of {1} meters at coordinates
>   {2}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))

This will give me an output like:

> Feature 1 has a length of 346.239783695 meters at coordinates
>   (470765.69285000017, 6313169.6829)

I want to drop the decimals (i.e., turn the values into integers for reporting purposes only) and just have

> Feature 1 has a length of 346 meters at coordinates (470765, 6313169)

How do I alter the format within the script to accomplish that? I assume it will be super easy and something I should know, but I've been out of the Arc/Python world for a few years.

Comment: This is a pure Python question that I can remember researching and finding a solution for at [so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished by taking full advantage of the `format` function you're already using. In its basic form (e.g. `'{0}'.format(var)`), the value returned is equivalent to `str(var)`. However, by adding stuff inside the curly braces, you can tweak the formatting quite extensively -- see [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

For your specific example, try this:

```
LogFile("Feature {0} has a length of {1:.0f} meters at coordinates ({2:.0f}, {3:.0f})".format(row[0], row[1], row[2][0], row[2][1]))
```

I had to separate the coordinates tuple into its individual components, as the float formatting doesn't work on tuples directly.

Comment: Thanks for that. I figured it was something simple. The tuple thing got me for a bit.
The following also seems to work

'LogFile("Feature {0} has a length of {1} meters at coordinates ({2}, {3})".format(int(row[0]), int(row[1]), int(row[2][0]), int(row[2][1])))'